# Options which require RuleDelayed

Tags: replacement, options

For some functions in *Mathematica* it is important to use `RuleDelayed`. One prominent example is the `EvaluationMonitor` for functions like `NMinimize`

```
NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 - x, x, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[x]]
```

Here it is inevitable to use `RuleDelayed` because otherwise `Print[x]` would be evaluated too soon.

**Question:** Is there a comprehensive list of options which require `RuleDelayed`?

Btw, the reason why I need this list is to support this correctly in the [IntelliJ Plugin for Mathematica](http://halirutan.de/plugin):

[image]

Comment: Oh, yes. It's the complement of the comprehensive list of all options with the comprehensive subset that requires a non-delayed rule. I'm still trying to find any of those too.

Comment: maybe there is an *enourmous* corpus of mathematica code somewhere (like that wolfram website i've seen), where you could extract these kinds of things semi-exhaustively? Just throwing that out as an idea.

Comment: I have a feeling there are also those options that can work with either of `Rule[]` or `RuleDelayed[]`, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: @J.M. You can always trick *Mathematica* like here `NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 - x, x, EvaluationMonitor -> Hold[Print[x]]]` but I think especially in the monitor options the user almost always wants `:>`. In many other cases it probably doesn't hurt to use `:>` in preference to `->`.

Comment: Then, there are the suboptions of options. One example that immediately comes to mind is the `"EventAction"` option of the `"EventLocator"` method of `NDSolve[]`.

Comment: @J.M. actually, if they use `OptionValue` all options can be expressed using either `Rule` or `RuleDelayed`. Whether it has any effect is how it is used internally. Do they call `OptionValue` every time (invoking `RuleDelayed` correctly), or do they capture the result? If they capture the result, do they use `Set` or `SetDelayed`? My standard method is to capture the result, but as I don't usually create mutable options, I use `Set`, fixing the value.

Comment: I tend to think that evaluation control is the user's responsibility. That said, it's a noble goal to offer hints where appropriate. I would just add that it's probably best for the resulting list to be subject to some human discretion before inclusion in the final product since there are quite a few scenarios where the "usual" or default choice is not applicable.

Comment: @rcollyer, anyway, I was implicitly talking about what Oleksandr now explicitly stated; it is a bit hard to simulate human discretion. "Yes, I wanted to use `->` here; stop bugging me!"

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yes, I'm fully aware that basically this discussion is useless, because in most places I can use either `->` or `:>` and in the end it's always the users decision. But making *option completion* insert the rule makes you type really fast and should the *usual* choice not fit, you can always go back and change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us start a community wiki answer where we collect possible `:>`-options because I think this question got enough attention by many of the experienced users to tell there isn't an easy way to get such a list automatically.

The reason for that is that the choice of the rule type is not fixed. You can almost always use `:>` instead of `->` and as I have shown in the comments even the other way around is possible

```
NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 - x, x, EvaluationMonitor -> Hold[Print[x]]]
```

The question here is: *If options would be inserted automatically like in the Mathematica front end, which ones should utilize `:>`?*. Please append more options below

```
{
 EvaluationMonitor, EventAction, Initialization, 
 InterpretationFunction, NotebookDynamicExpression, 
 StepMonitor, TrackedSymbols, UnsavedVariables, UntrackedVariables,

 CellDynamicExpression,

 (*GestureHandler: *)
 "Drag", "Pinch",

 (*EventHandler: *)
 PassEventsUp, "MouseClicked", "MouseDown", "MouseDragged", "MouseMoved", "MouseUp",
 "KeyDown", "ReturnKeyDown", "EscapeKeyDown", "LeftArrowKeyDown", "RightArrowKeyDown",
 "UpArrowKeyDown", "DownArrowKeyDown", "MenuCommand", "WindowClose",

 CellEpilog, CellProlog, DateFunction(*?*), Deinitialization, DialogProlog, DialogSymbols,
 Gradient(*evaluates only with the specific numerical values of variables that are needed*)
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I seem to recall 9.0.0 inserting a lot more `:>` than `->` even for options that normally don't need them (e.g. `PlotRange`)

Comment: @rm-rf Not under OSX. I have an old installation here and this doesn't do it.

Comment: Also `CellDynamicExpression`. (but not `FrontEndDynamicExpression`?) And maybe all events under `EventHandler`.

Answer (score 7):

One possible way to get *some candidates* is to test all `Options` of all `` System` `` symbols

```
extractRuleDelayedOptions[symbol_String] := 
 With[{opts = Options @@ MakeExpression[symbol]},
  Cases[opts, (p_ :> _) :> p]
];

Union@Flatten[extractRuleDelayedOptions /@ Names["System`*"]]
```

This produces the following list

```
{"Compiler", "CompilerWarnings", "Device", "Graphics", "Obsolete", 
"Packing", "Spelling", "Symbolics", "UserName", 
BoxForm`ActionFunction, Assumptions, BackgroundAppearance, 
ButtonFunction, ByteOrdering, CachedValue, CellDynamicExpression, 
CharacterEncoding, CompilationTarget, CoordinatesToolOptions, 
CounterFunction, DefaultFont, Deinitialization, DisplayFunction, 
DistributedContexts, DOSTextFormat, DynamicModuleParent, 
DynamicModuleValues, FormatType, FrontEndDynamicExpression, 
Initialization, NotebookDynamicExpression, NumberMarks, Path, 
PerformanceGoal, TextStyle, TimeZone, UnsavedVariables, 
UntrackedVariables}
```

which is not satisfactory mainly because `EvaluationMonitor` and `StepMonitor` which require `RuleDelayed` are not included. Who knows what further options we missed.

The problem with this approach is as follows: It doesn't tell you what `Options` require `:>` when they are used inside a function call. Here `:>` acts to make the standard values work.

Example: `Path` for instance should always be just a string and not require `:>`. The reason why in the default setting `:>` was utilized is because the default settings is

```
Path :> $Path
```

Therefore, the value of `$Path` is not evaluated until the rule is used. If `->` would have been used here, the default option would have the value of `$Path` at the moment of definition, and not at the moment of its usage.

Comment: Initialization and TrackedSymbols came to my mind immediately. The former is in your list, the latter isn't.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, I should have thought about this too since I used it quite often lately.

Comment: Monitor-like options (such as `NMinimize`) are warped by `Rule` (not `RuleDelayed`) and set to `None` as default. When monitoring something, we'll have to type `RuleDelayed`. In such cases, the auto-completion of _Mathematica_ 's front-end is wrong.(v9.0.0 in Windows7)

Comment: I would like to do this: `funcs = ToExpression /@ Flatten@(Names["System`" <> # <> "*"] & /@      CharacterRange["A", "Z"]);Select[funcs,  MemberQ[Options[#][[;; , 1]],  Monitor | EvaluationMonitor | StepMonitor] &]` . But I only pick up the monitor one, possibly missing other `RuleDelayed` cases.

Comment: I also noticed that `RuleDelayed` is added when using the auto-completion of `CompilationTarget` in `Compile`. Although both of `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` will work, the default should be `Rule` I think. Is this a small bug?

Comment: I just noticed this question, again, due to RM kicking it up on the front page. Some options don't require `RuleDelayed`, but use it to incorporate global actions, like `PerformanceGoal` which is usually set to `$PerformanceGoal`. So, as you point out in the CW answer, this is a difficult thing to do automatically.

Answer (score 7):

According to [@amr 's suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25703/options-which-require-ruledelayed#comment79791_25703), I scanned every **.nb** files under the **Mathematica\9.0\Documentation\English\** directory - which is fairly fast even on my outdated PC. This is what I got:

```
wsc = (WhitespaceCharacter ...);
prePtn = "RowBox[" ~~ wsc ~~ "{" ~~ wsc ~~ "\"";
inPtn = "\"" ~~ wsc ~~ "," ~~ wsc ~~ "\"";

rdOptExtractor = Function[testfile,
   Module[{fileStr},
    fileStr = Import[testfile, "String"];
    Function[ruleType,
        StringCases[fileStr, 
         Shortest[
           prePtn ~~ opt : Except[WhitespaceCharacter] .. ~~ inPtn ~~ 
            ruleOpr : ruleType ~~ "\""] :> opt]
        ] /@ {":>", "\[RuleDelayed]", "\\[RuleDelayed]"} // Flatten // Union
    ] ];

filelist = 
  FileNames["*.nb",{"D:\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\9.0\\Documentation\\English\\"}, ∞];

Length[filelist]
```

> 10416

```
AbsoluteTiming[res = Union[Flatten[rdOptExtractor /@ filelist]];]
```

> {504.27584,Null}

```
Cases[
 Union[Quiet[Check[
      ToExpression[#],
      StringReplace[#, "\\\"\\<" ~~ opt : __ ~~ "\\>\\\"" :> opt]
      ] & /@ res]],
 a_ /; MemberQ[{String, Symbol}, Head[a]]]
```

> ```
> {"-", "+", "10!", "4!", "7!", "a", "b", "back", "c", "dialog1", 
> "Drag", "\\<\\\"E1\\\"\\>", "\\<\\\"E2\\\"\\>", "E2", 
> "\\<\\\"E3\\\"\\>", "end", "EvaluationMonitor", "Event", 
> "EventAction", "halfway", "In", "Invariants", 
> "\\<\\\"listHead\\\"\\>", "listHead", "MethodMonitor", 
> "MouseClicked", "MouseDown", "MouseDragged", "MouseUp", "Off", "On", 
> "one", "\\<\\\"opt2\\\"\\>", "Out", "Pinch", "PositionVariables", 
> "print1", "Reset", "ReturnKeyDown", "start", "Subsubtitle", 
> "Subtitle", "Title", "two", "WindowClose", Assumptions, b, 
> bookmarkName, ButtonData, ButtonFunction, CellEpilog, CellProlog, 
> CharacterEncoding, DateFunction, Deinitialization, DialogProlog, 
> DialogSymbols, DisplayFunction, DistributedContexts, e, Epilog, 
> EvaluationMonitor, EventAction, FontFamily, FontSize, FormatType, g1, 
> g2, g3, g4, GeneratedParameters, Gradient, Initialization, 
> InterpretationFunction, List, NotebookDynamicExpression, NumberMarks, 
> ParameterVariables, PassEventsUp, Path, PerformanceGoal, PlotLabel, 
> Polygon, Prolog, RegionFunction, StepMonitor, TextStyle, TimeZone, 
> Tooltip, TrackedSymbols, UnsavedVariables, WordBoundary, x, y}
> ```

Of cause some elements in the above list are irrelevant, but unfortunately I can't figure out a good way to filter them out.

**Remaining work:**

I didn't scan **.m** files. Also there are still many *corpus* under **Mathematica\9.0\AddOns\** and **Mathematica\9.0\SystemFiles\**, which are worth looking-into.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 This is what I tried first, although I just used `fgrep` and searched only in the `ReferencePages` sub-folder. Like you I wasn't able to figure out a good criterion for selecting the relevant ones.

Comment: @halirutan Thanks! btw if reading the file as `Notebook` expressions I think it would be possible/easier to get inheritance relationships between options and their sub-options. It's so sad pattern matching is much slower in that case..