# Application example of RuleDelayed in options

Tags: function-construction, syntax, options, guidelines

In this question: [Options which require RuleDelayed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25703/options-which-require-ruledelayed) , an example was given, where the an option has to be given as a `RuleDelayed`: `EvaluationMonitor` of `NMinimize`.

But many other functions use `Functions` in the same application: take `ColorFunction` of `DensityPlot`.

Instead of usage

```
NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 - x, x, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[x]]
```

one could perhaps implemented `NMinimize` as

```
NMinimize[exp_, x_, ___, OptionsPattern[]] := 
   OptionValue[EvaluationMonitor][x]
```

Another example in [an answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25710/2036) was `Path :> $Path` which delays the evaluation, but in many applications `Automatic` is used instead, which then triggers evaluation.

In which applications are `RuleDelayed` useful for giving options? Are there applications, where the *lhs* of the option would be a pattern?

I would like to understand the design pattern and good practice behind these advanced features.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is, you can achieve the same with different idioms but some are better in some cases than another. Pick the one that reduces amount of code that you and user need to write because it will probably contribute to experience and robustness.

### Options which expect functions

`ColorFunction`, `MeshFunctions` etc all are supposed to be functions because **the author provides a fixed set of arguments** and it is up to the user what to do with them.

### Options with `:>`

Why not a function for `EvaluationMonitor`? Because, among others, `NMinimize` can have many different things in its *varspec*. It can be a symbol, list of symbols, `_ ∈ region_`, etc.

Either user would have to have parse it `MonitorFunction -> myMonitor @* standardizeVarspec` or the author would have to waste time to convert any *varsepc* to e.g. a list of symbols. Not worth the effort if user can just write `Print[x]`.

### Options with :> vs symbolic options

The gain in `Path :> $Path` case, except it obviously delays `$Path` evaluation, is that the author does not need to write `OptionValue[Path] /. Automatic -> $Path` etc. Not the major problem but that line can be half of its length. Additionally it is self documenting.

It may be worth it, if the default value (`$Path`) is simple and there is only one default value (for more you need to switch inside anyway).

If it is not simple it may be a pain to use when user writes a code that plays with that option. This is fine:

```
...
path = If[condition, customPath, $Path];
YourFunction[..., Path -> path]
...
```

This is not:

```
...
opt = If[condition, customOpt, complexValueOf[YourFunction's, Default->Option] (*made up example*) ];
YourFunction[..., Opt -> opt]
...
```

So here a symbolic options make more sense:

```
...
opt = If[condition, customOpt, Automatic ];
YourFunction[..., Opt -> opt]
...
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! You covered almost all of my concerns. How about *left side value* being a pattern? Does option like `Options[myfunc]={f[a_]:>g[a]}` have any application examples? It feels very powerful.

Comment: @Johu I am not sure how should that work, how would e.g. a call to `myfunc` look like? And how and what would you like to retrieve the option inside? What pros do you see here?

Comment: This was *my* question :).

Comment: @Johu I understood your question as 'where is this feature useful' while I am asking, but what feature? `Options[myfunc]={f[a_]:>g[a]}` is not enough for me to understand what do you mean.\

Comment: ok. thanks. I will add an extend example to the Q later.